# Show / hide table does'nt work on onchange dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-4

Apparently there isnt any error inside my console but when I click on an element inside the drop-down, a table must appear/disappear. This point doesn't work.

you can see in action here

```js
$('select[name=\'type\']').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value == 'select' || this.value == 'radio' || this.value == 'checkbox' || this.value == 'image') {
    $('#option-value').parent().show();
  } else {
    $('#option-value').parent().hide();
  }
});

$('select[name=\'type\']').trigger('change');

var option_value_row = 0

function addOptionValue() {
  html = '<tr id="option-value-row' + option_value_row + '">';
  html += '  <td class="text-left"><input type="hidden" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][option_value_id]" value="" />';
  html += '<img src="http://clicshopping.no-ip.biz/clicshopping_test/boutique/sources/third_party/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/us.svg" alt="Anglais" title="Anglais" width="16" height="12" /><input type="text" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][option_value_description][name][0]" value="" class="form-control" required aria-required="true" />';
  html += '<input type="hidden" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][option_value_description][language_id][0]" value="1" class="form-control" />';
  html += '<img src="http://clicshopping.no-ip.biz/clicshopping_test/boutique/sources/third_party/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/fr.svg" alt="Francais" title="Francais" width="16" height="12" /><input type="text" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][option_value_description][name][1]" value="" class="form-control" required aria-required="true" />';
  html += '<input type="hidden" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][option_value_description][language_id][1]" value="2" class="form-control" />';
  html += '  </td>';
  html += ' <td> <input type="file"  name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][image]" value="" accept="image/*" class="form-control" /><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1024"></td>';
  html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][sort_order]" value="" class="form-control" /></td>';
  html += '  <td class="text-right"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#option-value-row' + option_value_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="button_remove" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
  html += '</tr>';

  $('#option-value tbody').append(html);

  option_value_row++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="attributesGroupTabs" style="overflow: auto;">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-column flex-sm-row" role="tablist" id="myTab">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active">Géneral</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Valeurs option</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabsClicShopping">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="col-md-12 tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="code" class="col-2 col-form-label">en</label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="1" name="name[1]" class="form-control" required aria-required="true" required="" id="attributes_name" placeholder="Nom option" class="form-control" />&nbsp; </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="code" class="col-2 col-form-label">fr</label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="1" name="name[2]" class="form-control" required aria-required="true" required="" id="attributes_name" placeholder="Nom option" class="form-control" />&nbsp; </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="Type Html" class="col-5 col-form-label">Type Html</label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <select name="type" id="input-type" class="form-control"><option value="2">checkbox</option><option value="7">date</option><option value="9">datetime</option><option value="4">file</option><option value="1">radio</option><option value="5">select</option><option value="3">text</option><option value="6">textarea</option><option value="8">time</option></select>                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="Ordre de tri" class="col-5 col-form-label">Ordre de tri</label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="text" name="sort_order" value="0" placeholder="Ordre de tri" class="form-control" /> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <table id="option-value" class="table table-sm table-hover table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
              <td class="text-md-center" width="50%">Nom de la valeur</td>
              <td class="text-md-center" width="30%">Image</td>
              <td class="text-md-center" width="10%">Ordre de tri</td>
              <td class="text-md-right" width="10%">Action</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4"></td>
              <td class="text-right"><button type="button" onclick="addOptionValue();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="button_add" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of your options are all numbers, yet you compare the select value to strings such as “checkbox”, “radio”.

You could change the handler to look for the numeric values instead, or you could change the values of each option to be the strings you are expecting.